# Доступ к файлу Word

Tags: python

Не подскажите, как получить доступ к файлу Word, расположенном на рабочем столе?
Пишу следующий код:

```
import doc
import os
doc = Document('C:\Users\User\Desktop\7класс')
```

получаю следующую ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 3
    doc = Document('C:\Users\User\Desktop\7класс')
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/9210255

Answer (score 2):

```
('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\7класс')
```

или

```
(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\7класс')
```

Comment: Сделайте небольшое пояснение - в чём суть, чтобы задавший вопрос понял, что это за магия.

Comment: Необходимо получить доступ к файлу Word для работы с ним